# Two different show views for restful resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a job app with two kinds of (not-authenticated) users, referrers and candidates.

Currently I have 1 jobs controller and model.

Basically, I want to have two routes:

```
job/1 # jobs#show for referrers
j/1   # jobs#show for candidates
```

Both routes are public, there are no logged-in users.

While the model data (=content) is very similar for the two routes, the views are obviously different. I am struggling to create two different show views within the same controller.

I have looked at setting up a separate namespace (seems to be for the entire controller), specific get routes or setting up a separate controller, but really not sure what the best "Rails" way is.

Any suggestions would be really helpful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **JobsController** create two different methods. Say

```
def referrers
end

def cadidates
end
```

Now in your **routes.rb** add newly created methods as like,

```
get '/j/:id', :to => 'jobs#cadidates'
get '/job/:id', :to => 'jobs#referrers'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I want, but somehow it's giving me an error now: Missing template jobs/refferers, application/refferers in `def find(*args)
      find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))
    end` -- seems like it's not passing the correct @job?

Comment: @ruby24, there must be a template file, named `referrers.html.erb` and `cadidates.html.erb` for view. Those files should be placed in your `views/jobs` folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, had a typo and a conflict with `resources :jobs` in the routes file. Sorry for being such a noob!

Comment: @ruby24, Happy coding. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 options:

1) Create a separate action in your controller

```
def referrers
end 

def cadidates
end

get '/j/:id' => 'jobs#cadidates'
get '/job/:id' => 'jobs#referrers'
```

This requires two new views with the actions. In your job views folder add two files: candidates.erb and referrers.erb. You can there adjust the view for each.

2) You can nest the resources

```
  resources :job do
    member do
      get :referrers, :candidates
    end
  end
```

You would have to define a new model and create joint tables where both referrers and candidates are defined as users but part of different table referrers and candidates respectively.

Comment: I am trying to use 1), but somehow not sure how to pass the #show functionality to be able to have job/1, job/2, job/3 directly accessible while using separate referrers.html.erb and candidates.html.erb templates. Not sure how 2) would work given that I have no way to know the difference between a referrer and a candidate except from the URL. Thanks so much!